# Powershell: Trying to use regex to check for similarities in an IP and then with the result turn it into a MD5 hash

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to make code where it will change an IP through regex and then into MD5 so that it can still be traced back to be used in logs but not able to be identified personally for security reasons. When I run my code it would print out the IP's hash but then the last part's twice and nothing as shown:`

```
$s = "IPA:10.51.5.41"
$q="\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b"
$result = [regex]::Matches($s, $q)


$matchCount = $result.Groups.Count;
for ($num = 0; $num -lt $matchCount; $num++) {
    $individualMatch = $result.Groups[$num].Value;
    Write-Host "num is " + $individualMatch;
    
    $md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($individualMatch)))
    Write-Host "hash is " + $hash;
}`
```

results:

```
num is  + 10.51.5.41
hash is  + AE-B5-C4-0C-27-83-74-33-55-E4-6B-A2-BE-5A-35-F6
num is  + 41
hash is  + 34-16-A7-5F-4C-EA-91-09-50-7C-AC-D8-E2-F2-AE-FC
num is  + 41
hash is  + 34-16-A7-5F-4C-EA-91-09-50-7C-AC-D8-E2-F2-AE-FC
num is  + 
hash is  + D4-1D-8C-D9-8F-00-B2-04-E9-80-09-98-EC-F8-42-7E
```

I want to have the first part and remove the rest and the error could be because of my regex. Thank you

Comment: Please post your code as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the whole IP address and not the capture groups at the end, *don't loop through all the capture groups*:

```
# We can reuse the same MD5 provider, no need to create a new one every time
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

# Extract all IP addresses
$s = "IPA:10.51.5.41"
$q="\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b"
$result = [regex]::Matches($s, $q)

# Loop through each match (not each group in each match)
foreach($match in $result){
    if($match.Success){
        Write-Host "Input is: '$($match.Value)'"
        $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($match.Value)))
        Write-Host "Hash is:  '${hash}'"
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using regex, wouldn't it be more direct to just split at the `:` and take the last part?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It would, but that's not the question OP asked :)

Comment: oops! i got distracted ... thanks for the answer, tho! [*grin*]